# Strange obstacle in appending strings in java

Tags: java

i wanna append some sub string to a string variable that name is Request but it doesn't work and Request stay empty with "" value. it is really strange.
Request is StringBuilder and  a member of my class.
Client is an instance of Socket.
note: tmp is not empty ...

anybody can help me? 
(codes changed)

```
class Threading extends Thread
{
Socket server;
Socket client;
StringBuilder Request;

Threading(Socket sck,Socket srv)
{
    client = sck;
    server = srv;
    Request = new StringBuilder();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try
    {
        DataOutputStream clientout = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader clientinput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("---------REQUEST--------");
        String tmp ="THIS";

        while((tmp=clientinput.readLine())!=null)
        {
            Request = Request.append(tmp);
        }
        System.out.println(Request.toString());//Request is empty!!!
        DataOutputStream srvout = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader srvin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
        srvout.write(Request.toString().getBytes());
        while((tmp=srvin.readLine())!=null)
        {
            clientout.write(tmp.getBytes());
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

i put all of my class codes.
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: it is an instance of a StringBuilder class.

Comment: If your request is empty, then your file is empty.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea He's not reading from a file. Which file are you referring to?

Comment: @JoshM sorry, the stream is empty.

Comment: What is `client`? Is it a File object? Can you show the code?

Comment: guys , even if replace Request with a String variable and using it like this : 
Request += tmp;
it doesnt work yet...

Comment: @PopoFibo , i said tmp is not empty. yet i did your idea but it is still empty.

Comment: Insert into your loop: `System.out.println("Read "+tmp)`, `System.out.println("Request before append: "+Request)` and `System.out.println("Request after append: "+Request)` , or run it in a debugger

Comment: when i print tmp in each perform of while it prints all data without any problem.
whie(...)
{system.out.peintln(tmp);}
it works.it means tmp has data. even Request has data in while block but after while bock it change to null value.

Comment: Side notes: 1) Variable names starting with uppercase are extremely uncommon in Java programming. 2) Assigning the result of `Request.append(..)` to `Request` again is completely unnecessary if it is indeed an an instance of `StringBuilder`.

Comment: request.append(...) without assigning to request doesn't work yet.

Comment: (One could, of course, simply hardcode all of the first N fibonacci numbers, turning this into a table lookup and reducing it to O(1) time.)

Comment: @keshlam it isn't possible to turn it to O(1). because i don't know how many bytes have been sent to me.so i have to read specified number of bytes in each perform of a loop or read a line from input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I am running a little modified version of your code (for not dealing with sockets) and I get the expected behaviour:

Maybe another thread overwriting `Request`? Try using a local variable.
Are you 100% sure clientinput has data? including newline??

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Tmp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Tmp().run();
}

StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder(); 
public void run() {

    String test= "testData\r\n";
    ByteArrayInputStream client = new ByteArrayInputStream(test.getBytes()); 
    try
    {
        BufferedReader clientinput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client));
        System.out.println("---------REQUEST--------");
        String tmp;

        while((tmp=clientinput.readLine())!=null)
        {
            request = request.append(tmp);
        }
        System.out.println(request.toString());//request is NOT empty!!!
    }
    catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}         
}
```